# Legend disappears when plotting a SpatRaster with a color table

Tags: r, terra

I wanted to visualize a land cover dataset that comes with a specific color table. When using `plot()`, each class is plotted in the color specified in this table. However, the legend seems to be missing.

I executed the code from the [color table help page](https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/colors.html) and had the same problem.

```
r <- rast(ncols=3, nrows=2, vals=1:6)
coltb <- data.frame(value=1:6, col=rainbow(6, end=.9))
plot(r)
```

gives the regular plot including the legend: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crcqs.png)

But after doing

```
coltab(r) <- coltb
plot(r)
```

I get a plot without legend: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noJF9.png)

Am I missing something here? Do I need to supply the `plot()` function with an additional argument? How can I work around this in the easiest way? Setting a color table for a SpatRaster with `coltab()` is a nice feature but not of much use if the legend is not plotted.